# API Version and Ant Deployment tool

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

The package.xml in my git repo has an API version near the bottom:

```
<version>47.0</version>
```

When I deploy to a development branch org, it's OK.
When I retrieve from the branch org, there are many changes I do not recognise. This I ascribe to the difference in API version. When retrieved from my org, it says:

```
<version>44.0</version>
```

How can I upgrade my org to version 47?

Answer (score 2):

It's not that your org needs to be "upgraded", it's most likely your Ant salesforce-ant.jar file is outdated. Salesforce always runs on the latest version and is updated automatically during the release window. Try downloading the newest version, or consider installing the new Salesforce DX CLI instead.

Comment: thanks, but I just downloaded the latest salesforce-ant.jar, no change.